# How to get mandatory or optional cookies details in classic asp

Tags: asp.net

I have one requirement, To get all cookies details which are being used in entire application and also find is cookies are mandatory or optional ?
As per my analysis i can get the cookies details but unable to find is it mandatory or optional. Can anyone help me on the same.

Comment: Your question says asp classic but your tag says asp.net , which is it ?

Comment: I hope the project is requiring you to convert all the cookies into session or database values.

Comment: If you are looking for a one click, or CLI quick fix for this, it doesn't exist.  The good news is it sounds like you can generate a list of all the Cookies that are used, so the actual real solution is to work each one and find out for yourself, because optional and mandatory are arbetrary terms defined by the website developer and not some settings that HTML has updated (correct me if I am wrong someone?)

Comment: I thought about this for a bit, and I have an idea, but I only know how to do it in ASP Classic.  But I suspect you could make this work in .NET too.  Classic has the file object, you could read every file in the directory searching fo all the cookie tags, in classic it you could search for something like "Request.Cookies" and then build an array of all the found cookies, and then display that array.  Perhaps gather useful info along the way, like what page and other values you might want.   That being said, I'm hoping .NET has similar abilities, but that would be one way to do it.

Comment: And of note to address the last part of the question, how to find out which ones are optional or mandatory?  Unless the programmer put a tag into the cookie name to help you sort them, the only way to know is to test each one, removing it, and see if it fails or not.  And then my suggestion would be rename it to be cookie_mandatory_cookiename  vs cookie_optional_cookiename or something like that, so that way NOW the app would have a way to indicate if the cookie was mandatory or not.